# User analytics and behaviour tracking with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-views, analytics, django-rest-framework, mixpanel

I want to find out analytics and create an user story each time different views (Django rest framework views) are called (as endpoints) by a client (iPhone app)

I found out here : http://mixpanel-celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html to do this using mixpanel-celery

So, it involves me having to write a few lines of almost the same code (i.e. the name of the view as the name of the event (like FeedView or NotificationView or ProfileView, the id and name of the request.user). Is there any way to follow DRY and refactor this code somewhere, or does a library like this exist in conjunction with django views /rest framework views?

```
result = EventTracker.delay(
'my_event',
{'distinct_id': 1},
token='YOUR_API_TOKEN',
)
result.wait()
```